# Google Spreadsheets: Using conditional formatting from date in another cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have two columns side by side containing dates. The dates in column A are based on when a project is due. The dates in column B are based on when a project is completed. What I want to do is show Dates completed in column B in red that are past the due date listed in Column A. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
Col A 1/9/2015  Col B 1/9/2015 (no formatting)
Col A 1/12/2015 Col B 1/13/2015 (formatted red)
Col A 1/12/2015 Col B 1/9/2015 (no formatting)
Col A 1/12/2015 Col B 1/19/2015 (formatted red)
Col A 1/12/2015 Col B 1/7/2015 (no formatting)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Please select ColumnB, Format - Conditional formatting..., **Custom formula is**:

```
 =B1>A1
```

and select red.

Answer (score 0):

Select all the cells in column B
--> Conditional formatting
--> Custom Formula=  B1:B5>$A1

Hope it helps.